# Simpler possible definition of martingale?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, martingales, expected-value

Wikipedia defines as follows:

> A basic definition of a martingale is a discrete-time stochastic
>   process that satisfies for any time $n$:
>
> $$\mathbf{E} ( \vert X_n \vert ) < \infty $$
>
> $$\mathbf{E} (X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)=X_n$$

The second formula seems to indicate that the only thing that matters for the expectation is the previous value. Can we not just write:

$$\mathbf{E} (X_{n+1} \mid X_n)=X_n$$

Or is this somehow not equivalent? If they are not equivalent what is a counter example? It seems by not using $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ on the right hand side we are already indicating that they don't matter.

Comment: I can think about a counterexample. However, the key issue is that Martingales are not necessarily Markov chains. You could have a Martingale that satisfies,

$$E(X_{n+1}|X_n) = X_n,$$

for which

$$E(X_{n+1}|X_n,\dots,X_1) \neq  E(X_{n+1}|X_n)=X_n.$$

In that case, $X$ would not be a Martingale.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Y_1,Y_2$ be independent with standard normal distribution. Let $X_1=Y_1,X_2=Y_1+Y_2,X_n=2Y_1$ for $n \geq 3$. Then $E(X_{n+1} |X_n)=X_n$ for all $n$. [For $n=2$ write $2Y_1$ as $(Y_1+Y_2)+(Y_1-Y_2)$ and use the well know fact that $Y_1+Y_2$ and $Y_1-Y_2$ are independent]. However $E(X_3|X_1,X_2)=2Y_1\neq X_2$.

Comment: I don't see how "Then $E(X_{n+1} |X_n)=X_n$ for all $n$." From what you wrote it looks like $E(X_2 | X_1) \neq X_1$, because $X_2$ is defined to include adding $Y_2$ which $X_1$ does not include, which will surely change the expectation? I don't see how your suggestion for how to rewrite changes this.

Comment: Are you familiar with basic properties of conditional expectation? $E(X_2|X_1)=E(Y_1+Y_2|Y_1)=E(Y_1|Y_1)+E(Y_2|Y_1)=Y_1+EY_2=Y_1+0=Y_1=X_1$.

Comment: Also $E(X_3|X_2)=E(2Y_1|Y_1+Y_2)=E(Y_1+Y_2|Y_1+Y_2)+E(Y_1-Y_2|Y_1+Y_2)=Y_1+Y_2+E(Y_1-Y_2)=Y_1+Y_2+0=Y_1+Y_2=X_2$.